# Improve SSRS sub-report performance

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In my parent report I have 4 sub reports (say  A, B , C, D) . Performance is not good. So I tried to prepare one report which is having all 4 reports( A, B , C , D ) not using sub reports.

Here in both the cases I am facing performance issue. Could some one please guide me which way is good to implement. using sub report or using one single report. In this case we have same parameters?

Comment: I would imagine that either as 4 sub reports or one report combining the 4 would result in the same performance issue. I would recommend taking a look at what the report is compiling and check for performance inefficiencies there.

Comment: I agree with Anthony. Go back and review the report queries and analyze them for why they are too slow. In many cases a slow query might simply be using a poor query plan - eg. missing index, outdated statics, poorly written query, non-sargable model. (Use SSMS to run the queries and view the actual query plan used. SSMS will provide hints on grossly missing indices.)

Comment: Also consider designing your queries to only run once and then caching them or using a single report and filtering the query as needed in the report. Often subreports are slow because they run similar queries many times.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue, but no solution was good enough.
My solution is...

1. create a shared dataset and deploy
2. on SSRS website activate caching for this dataset (to 5 mins or so)
3. in SSRS report filter the dataset (not filter the query behind dataset !)

I had 1 subreport which was called 25 times...each SQL call took 0.8 seconds, but 25 x 0.8 :-(

Now the report renders in 2 seconds

Comment: Caching subreport datasets significantly improved my report performance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know I understood your requirements properly or not but i guise you may use action facility of SSRS to load only one sub-report at a time it will execute only one report at a time which may solve your problem of performance as you will show only one report which is required at a time and which will be there for as long as your report doesn't gets closed.

In case you have any specific requirements of yours then please let me know, we can try to resolve your queries.

Thank You